# strict growth in open interval

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$f:\left[a,b\right]\to \mathbb{R}$. While $f^\prime>0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, the function is strictly increasing in $[a,b]$.

What could one do if one had $f:\left(a,b\right)\to \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you try to explain what you mean?

Comment: For example, one could go out and play in the sun ...

Comment: Yes. I can use the sentence to figure out if a function has strict growth in a given **closed** interval. If I then have a function defined in an open interval, I would not be able to use the sentence to prove if the function has strict growth or not. How would I go about solving the issue?

Comment: @Adayah Yes, thank you for pointing out the error. Fixed now.

Comment: I think OP is not well versed with math notations, what he/she wants to know is if a function is defined on an open interval, what condition is needed to safely say that it is strictly increasing in the interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a real-valued function mapping from $[a,b]$ that is differentiable in the open interval $(a,b)$ and satisfies $f^{\prime}>0$ there. Then, by the mean value theorem, we can find $c\in(a,b)$ such that
$$
f^{\prime}(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.
$$
Then, since $f^{\prime}(c)>0$ and $b-a>0$,
$$
f(b)-f(a)=f^{\prime}(c)(b-a)>0
$$
and hence $f(b)>f(a)$. Now, if we have points $x$ and $y$ satisfying $a<x<y<b$, choosing the interval $[x,y]\subset[a,b]$ and appying the same argument as above yields
$$
f(x)-f(y)>0.
$$
This proves that $f$ is strictly increasing.

---

Now, suppose you have a *bounded* differentiable function $g$ defined on the open interval $(a,b)$ that still satisfies $g^{\prime}>0$ there. An easy way to see that the strict increasing property still applies to this function is to define a new function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}g(x) & \text{if }x=a\\
g(x) & \text{if }a<x<b\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow b}g(x) & \text{if }x=b.
\end{cases}
$$
Since $g$ is bounded and continuous on $(a,b)$, the limits above are real numbers.
By the previous paragraph, $f$ is strictly increasing, and hence so too is $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, very helpful. What if the function was not continuous/not defined in a or b? Would you go about this using limits or such?

Comment: Notice the assumption of boundedness. If this assumption does not hold (e.g., $-\cot x$ on the interval $(0, \pi)$), then the strictly increasing property is still true so long as you interpret $\pm \infty$ as being bigger/smaller than any real number.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're asking.

If a function $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ this means that for all $x, y \in [a,b]$ with $x<y$, one has that $f(x)<f(y)$. In particular, if $x, y \in (a,b)$ with $x<y$, then $f(x)<f(y)$.

Therefore, if $f$ is strictly increasing on $[a,b]$ it is also strictly increasing on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is what I'm looking for. Sorry for being vague, but it's has been bugging me.

Comment: What is the function happened not to be defined or continuous in either a or b?